# Is There a Fitness / Activity Tracker which Measures Heart Beat Rate?

Tags: exercise-equipment, tracking, fitbit

Is there any activity tracker (For the wrist, like FitBit or JawBone) which measures the heart rate in addition to all the other measurements?

They all seem just to measure insignificant statistics.

Thank You.

Comment: Shouldn't a heart rate monitoring equipment be close to the heart?

Comment: There should be technologies which enable measuring the heart rate at different places.

Comment: I think the Samsung Gear 2 and Samsung Gear Fit do that. But I don't know if they classify as activity trackers. And also you need a Samsung phone...

Comment: Its about features on a tracker, rather than how to use the tracker in a program.

Comment: @JohnP, Why did you put on hold? It seems to raise interest of people and most of ll, equipment is integrated in modern fitness. I think it is legitmate question like http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24068/is-there-a-good-activity-tracker-in-terms-of-calories-spent-for-skating-and-cy?rq=1, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16481/heart-rate-monitoring-for-crossfit?rq=1 and many others.

Comment: @royi if you note, one I vtc but was not a mod at the time. The other hs the intended use as part of tge question. Gear and gadgets are on topic if they are part of a program, "recommend/find me x" are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few heart rate monitor fitness trackers coming soon to the market.  I'm sure many of us (including me) are anxiously awaiting something that can accurately measure calorie expenditure, rather than relying on a pedometer.  Obviously, nobody wants to have to inconveniently strap a heart rate monitor around their chest.

Here are some options you may keep your eye on for releases in the near future:

- [Atlas Fitness Tracker](http://uncrate.com/stuff/atlas-fitness-tracker/) $160 USD
- [Amiigo Fitness Band](https://amiigo.com/) $99 USD
- [The Dash In-Ear Smart Headphones](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hellobragi/the-dash-wireless-smart-in-ear-headphones) $199 USD
- [Samsung Gear 2 and Gear Fit](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/gear/gearfit_features.html) $199 USD

Already on the market (or almost on the market) are some other watches/wristbands that might suit your needs, such as:

- [Mio LINK Wristband](http://www.mioglobal.com/Mio-LINK-White--Heart-Rate-Wristband/Product.aspx?ProductID=15&DeptID=1) $99 USD
- [Basis Carbon Steel Edition](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/basis-health-tracker-for-fitness-sleep-stress-carbon-steel/3487007.p) $199 USD
- [TomTom Runner Cardio](http://www.tomtom.com/en_us/products/your-sports/running/tomtom-runner-cardio-gps-watch/white/index.jsp) $270 USD
- A cursory google search should yield quite a few other options in this department.

Another option is the Withings Pulse, which is a little widget that doesn't really fall into any of these categories:

- [Withings Pulse](http://vitrine.withings.com/us/withings-pulse.html) $86 USD

And maybe somewhere way down the line, you'll be able to have a smart contact lens that watches your heart rate as well, such as:

- [Google Smart Contact Lens](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/introducing-our-smart-contact-lens.html)

Comment: And why is it inconvenient to "strap a heart rate monitor around" your chest?

Comment: @rrirower Because if you want to wear it all day, it's not comfortable, difficult to take off and put on, and looks strange under a dress shirt.

Comment: Heart rate monitors aren't typically worn all day.  And, besides, isn't that just your opinion?

Comment: @rrirower Well, thanks to the upcoming wearable tech, they *can* be worn all day.  People want a more accurate representation of activity level than a pedometer can provide.  They want to be able to track their heart rate all day.  That is why these products exist.  And no, it's not just *my* opinion.  I imagine most everyone would agree it's more comfortable to wear a fitness band all day than a chest strap, and it's more convenient for a number of reasons.  The point can be argued, but what's that got to do with the poster's question?

Comment: @Doc, Thank You. The Atlas and Amiigo looks great.

Comment: Anyone knows on more products?

Comment: I use the Mio Fuse silicone band. Very comfortable, 3ATM waterproof, has sleep monitor. My kids also wear them and swim and sleep with them. Mio holds the patent on the optical heart rate sensor that is used on other devices mentioned, from Garmin to Apple. Since it's silicone, it can be weak if you're rough with your wrist. Normal wear is fine (I do martial arts and it survives). If you work on cars or hit rough edges, you can wear your sleeve over it, or use a sweat band to temporarily cover it to avoid cutting the silicone. I like the readout led of the fuse as it is easy to see.

Comment: I also used to wear a chest band for a long time.  A believer in it's superiority until the Mio Fuse. I'd say accuracy is on par but usefulness is way better for the Mio Fuse. Most watches that accompany chest bands aren't very easy to see, especially if your activity involves very fast hand movements like martial arts or swimming or  paddling at high stroke rates. You can see all that with the Fuse.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Watch heart rate monitor is surprisingly accurate for not having to wear a rib cage band. Especially with the [watchOS 3](https://www.idropnews.com/news/watchos-3-to-feature-a-slew-of-new-apps-for-home-reminders-heart-rate-and-more/19978/), where there is a dedicated app for heart rate monitoring. Try it! I can't live without it now that the Apple Watch is swim-proof.

Answer (score 1):

We have tested the Vivoactive HR, and it measures different times during the day, and pairs it to your activity. However it might be to bulky for small wrists.
I have not tested the apple watch 2, but some say it is improved a lot in measurements, like calorie burning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the new apple watch is what you need. It can measure your heart rate and provide more informations.

But yes, at least you need to pay 300$, but you get more then a monitor, but a smart watch. I have one and I think it is great!

Comment: I see... It is an option, though I'm more into the open approach of Microsoft Band. How accurate the Apple Watch HR Monitor? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -2):

As ZOD has indicated, for a more accurate record of heart rate, the standard practice is to wear a heart rate monitor belt paired with a wrist watch receiver.  [Polar](http://www.polar.com/us-en) heart rate monitors are a leader in that industry.